# Concatenating 0's to string in C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to add 0's on to the end of a c string such that the total length is 100.

So for example if string is "hi", I wanna add 98 0's.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: The homework tag is deprecated. Look in the sidebar =>

Comment: You only need to add 97 zeros, since the C string already has one.

Comment: @kprobst Oh, didn't noticed that. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify if it is '\0' or '0' that you want added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Malloc memory for 100 characters.  Memset all characters to '0' and then set the first 2 characters to hi.

Answer (score 1):

Cue the one liners!

```
// this does exactly what you want
// first two chars are 'h' and 'i', all the rest are 0.
char myString[100] = {'h', 'i'};
```

Comment: Really? How can you print this to the console?

Comment: @JacobRelkin, I didn't see this as a requirement in the question?  Are you assuming there is a console?

Comment: Yes, if I call `printf("%s", myString);` I should see `hi` plus 98 zeros.

Comment: @JacobRelkin, yes you certainly could if you are okay with the malloc. It is another fine option for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
static inline char *newPaddedStringToLength(const char *string, const char character, unsigned length) {
    if(strlen(string) >= length) return NULL;

    char *newString = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
    memset(newString, character, length);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < strlen(string); ++i) {
        newString[i] = string[i];
    }
    return newString;
}

char *string = "Blah";
char *padded = newPaddedStringToLength(string, '0', 100);


//...

if(padded) free(padded);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) can i suggest you use NULL instead?

2) There are no strings in C.

I assume your working on some sort of binary format.

If you have a char array that you want to be 100 chars long a char is represented as a byte in ascii.

You can alloc a char array that is 100 bytes long

and write the h and i bytes and you should have 98 null bytes. If you actually want zeros write 0 bytes to the rest.

You could use a loop.

Comment: `NULL` would be inappropriate. `NULL` represents the null pointer constant (and a C implementation could define it to be `(void*) 0`. http://c-faq.com/null/varieties.html

Comment: i guess im thinking if it is in fact for a binary file format. Where you'd want 98 null bytes? If this is wrong i'll just remove the answer, i know more about formatted binary data than actual c i guess. I don't know why you'd want to actually do what the asker is asking other than binary data transfer / storage. How would you represent a binary null \x00 ? For instance fixed string sizes in the protocol / format.

Comment: If you want an all-bits-zero byte, just use `0`.  Why would you need some other representation for that?

Comment: I meant the integer literal `0`, not the `char` literal `'0'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string name[100] = {'h', 'i'}'
```

This is the easiest way ti initialize a string.

Here the compiler will but the first 2 chars with `h` and `i` and the others with null chars (`\0` or `0`) both are the same.